# Validate that the console input contains positive integers only

Tags: python, validation

The function validates whether the input is an int, is there a way to make this more concise and is it best practise to use the try/except or just if/else? I then want to create a similar function for checking whether the input contains letters only using isalpha()

```
def int_validation(prompt):
    """
    Validate the given input is a positive number
    """

    while True:
        answer = input(prompt)
        if not answer:
            print(blank_input)
        else:
            try:
                answer = int(answer)
            except ValueError:
                print(positive_int_only)
                continue
            if answer < 1:
                print(positive_int_only)
            break
    return answer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest that when posting code for review that it be a complete. For example, variables `blank_input` and `positive_int_only` are undefined. Moving on:

Your `while True` loops suggests that you want to repeatedly prompt the user for a positive number until a valid positive number is entered and then return its value. You do repeatedly loop when the user enters an empty string or a string that cannot be parsed as a number (*but not necessarily an integer*)  but not if a non-positive number is entered. In this case you return the invalid non-positive input. **That is an inconsistency** and I will assume that this was an oversight on your part. But right now your docstring states that the purpose of the function is to validate that an input is a positive integer. What the function is actually doing is accepting input from a user until a valid positive integer is entered and returning that value.

```py
def int_validation(prompt):
    """
    Prompt the user for input until a positive integer
    is entered.
    """

    while True:
        answer = input(prompt)
        # No need to distinguish between blank input vs,
        # an invalid number:
        try:
            int_answer = int(answer)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            if int_answer >= 1:
                return int_answer
        print('You must enter a positive integer.')

print(int_validation('Enter a positive integer: '))
```

This will accept input such as `1e2` as valid. If you want to reject this as valid input then you need to ensure the input string contains only numeric digits.

**So if you require that the input be strictly composed of only digits, my preference would be to use a regular expression for validation:**

```py
import re

def int_validation(prompt):
    """
    Prompt the user for input until a positive integer
    is entered.
    """

    while True:
        answer = input(prompt).strip()
        # Allow leading zeroes, but they must be followed by a non-zero:
        if re.fullmatch(r'0*[1-9][0-9]*', answer):
            return int(answer)
        print('You must enter a positive integer.')

print(int_validation('Enter a positive integer: '))
```

You might consider defining a default value form the *prompt* argument if it is not supplied.

Comment: I like the """number""" vs `int()` distinction. // "_possible for the user to enter, for example, 1.23 and your code will accept that and return a 1._" I don't understand that, as `int("1.23")` raises ValueError: invalid literal. // Your proposed regex won't let me enter `1_000_000` for a million. In many cases it's sensible to let the high-level code define "error" identically to how the low-level (`int()`) library defines it. That is, propagate errors without trying any fancy second guessing of whether it seems likely that an input shall provoke an error. EAFP / LBYL.

Comment: @J_H You are correct about `int("1.23")` and I have updated my answer accordingly (I must have had a brain malfunction). As far as accepting `1_000_000`, that notation has meaning within a Python program and, yes, it will be a valid argument to the `int` constrictor -- and that is the problem and why I prefer the regex solution: **To an end-user this notation is *not standard nor natural*** and is only readily supported in Python programs using the `int` constructor. But if OP needs to rewrite this in code in, for example, PHP, now extra code is needed to support the unnatural syntax.